# What are approaches to model state-level estimates from a national estimate and state level correlates?

Tags: predictive-models, elections, politics

I want to model current levels of Presidential approval at the state level, based on (a) national poll (averages) of Presidential approval and (b) state level variables, particularly the percent votes for Biden in the 2020 election, and potentially adding demographic or other political variables. This is because there are few Presidential approval polls at the state level.

What approach(es) could I take to model Presidential approval in each of the 50 states? Ideally I would like to avoid digging through the crosstabs to perform a meta-analysis of how people respond at the state level as this seems cumbersome (these are also unweighted estimates), but I am curious if there are any viable alternatives.

**EDIT**: I failed to mention that I *do* have sample data which I can use to determine the correlation / build models between Presidential approval and 2020 vote choice. So far the hacky approach I've been taking is to build simple regression models based on this data and then to apply on simulated data where the proportion of Biden voters equals the historic proportion in that state.

Comment: Hi, just to help with Googling, you may be interested in the term "small area estimation".

Comment: Thanks @JohnMadden!